# Setting the URL for a JMS connection

Tags: java, jms, message-queue

The [JMS Hello World](http://www.sw-engineering-candies.com/snippets/java/hello-world-java-message-service-with-open-mq) example shows producers and consumers sending and consuming messages; this is how they seem to create the connection:

```
ConnectionFactory cf = new com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory();
Connection connection = cf.createConnection();
```

How specify the address and parameters of the remote JMS server?

I want to create an encrypted and compressed connection to an OpenMQ server that is running on another machine.  Ideally I would like to use both client and server authentication.

Comment: producers can send message but consumer can not send message

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://java.dzone.com/news/jms-over-http-using-openmq-sun) seems to provide an example using JMS server address.

This is how it creates a connection. They provide the address and also username and password (admin).

```
String addressList = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/imqhttp/tunnel";
com.sun.messaging.TopicConnectionFactory topicConnectionFactory = new com.sun.messaging.TopicConnectionFactory();
topicConnectionFactory.setProperty(com.sun.messaging.ConnectionConfiguration.imqAddressList, addressList);
javax.jms.Topic top;
javax.jms.Connection con = topicConnectionFactory.createTopicConnection("admin", "admin");
```